# Slope of the tangent line in Calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the slope of the tangent line to
$c(x) = e^{g(x)}$

$$g(x) = 2\:,\:g'(x) =-2$$

I tried and my answer was $-14.7781122$ but it was wrong ! why ?

Comment: Is there a certain accuracy that's required or exact form?

Answer (score 1):

You look for the slope of the tangent line on the point of the curve with abscissa $x$:

$$c'(x)=g'(x)e^{g(x)}=-2e^2$$

Comment: Unless I typo-ed somewhere, -2e^2 = -14.778...

Comment: Thaaanks ! that's clear now

Comment: You're welcome.@user157908

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Take}\  h(x)=e^x \Rightarrow \ h(g(x)) = c(x)=e^{g(x)} \text{we have a composition, so use chain rule.}$$

$$\ (h \circ g)^{'}(x) = h'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) = e^{g(x)}\cdot -2 = -2e^2.$$

Comment: Thanks, you made it clear !